# mysterious MissingMethodException for Webdriver cssSelector method

Tags: java, groovy, webdriver

Using Webdriver 2.25.0 in groovy with this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
...
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.test"))
```

Shows:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.openqa.selenium.By.cssSelector() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
```

The [docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) state this method is valid.  I can't figure out how this method is not resolving, whereas "name()" is.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct WebDriver version on the class path? What does `By.methods.findAll { it.name == "cssSelector" }` print?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. I was using the HtmlUnitDriver, which [apparently](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/om3IR58boGI) doesn't [implement](http://www.goodercode.com/wp/use-css-selectors-with-htmlunit/) By.cssSelector.  You can imagine my surprise, since seemingly up-to-date docs [indicate otherwise](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html).

I may be able to track down replacement functionality with a "querySelector" method on  com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode , but I have yet to figure out the relationship between com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit and org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit .